# Display media from HTC One on a computer display

Tags: linux, streaming, macos, htc-one, dlna

The title says it all. I am wondering if I can display slideshows among other things on a computer display.

I know that it has to be a DLNA compatible device, which I believe most of computer displays are not, and I also know there's this companion HTC Media Link HD device (which is a wi-fi dongle kind of thing).

I have a Mac OS X 10.8.2 Macbook Air, and an old Linux laptop, and some time to kill on a cold November weekend, so what I am asking really is whether there is a way to turn my Macbook or Linux laptop into a DLNA compatible device so that I could play slideshows on 24" display without investing any extra money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need DLNA for that, nor HDMI. WiFi and the right app might do as well. Take a look at e.g. [Remote Gallery 3D](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Media-Show-on-PC/com.androidsx.easygallery), you cannot only have a slide show on your PC, but even manage your photos remotely. The app runs a web server on your device, which then can be accessed via any web browser (i.e. completely OS independent). Only requirement is Flash capability. For a presentation, also have a look at [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6J6v_0SZM0).

This way you can even take your photo gallery with you when visiting friends or family: no installation on the PC required. So as long as WiFi is available, you're fine. The app is free, so it comes *without investing any extra money*, as requested ;)

---

Alternatively, you could setup a DLNA server on your Android device ([BubbleUPnP](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp) would be a good choice for that). Nex, you would need a client to access it from your Mac (take a look at [this Wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UPnP_AV_media_servers_and_clients#OS_X) to pick one). Start the server on your Android device, then start the client on the Mac. The Client should automatically find and list your Android device, and let you browse your media. What features are offered (just pick single entries, make a slideshow, have background music played along) depends on the client chosen.

---

A third variant would be investigating in [Airplay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPlay#AirPlay_Mirroring). As that's Apple's own stuff, your Mac should surely support it. There are [a bunch or apps supporting Airplay](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=airplay) you could chose from; not having a Mac, I cannot be of assistance in this area.

---

#### Fazit by [ILIV](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/46135/iliv):

> BUbbleUPnP is a very nice software. I'm having a lot of fun trying out various combinations. One thing I learned this morning is that I can use VLC to browse and play all content on my phone: video, music and pictures. Video playback intermittently stucks for a split second, very rarely, but it does. That is unfortunate, but I'm wondering if it is a VLC or BubbleUPnP issue, or maybe it's just that two don't get along well.

Comment: I also found out yesterday that I can display photos from Gallery via XMBC quite easily, including slideshow in a dumbed down version, i.e. no sound and fancy transition effects. Video and music can also be streamed from XBMC to HTC One, but this always puzzled me.. I mean, who wants to watch videos on a tiny screen or listen to music for too long on a batter powered device when they're at home and their computer/HTPC device is right there. Anyway, yeah, XBMC was a very easy to configure solution. Thank you for the tip, I will try Remote Gallery 3D too.

Comment: If you prefer a DLNA based solution, I could update my answer to include that as well. No big magic involved, and no "extra money" either.

Comment: Unfortunately, Remote Gallery 3D failed to work. And yes, if you can explain how DLNA (or rather UPnP in caxe with XBMC) can be configured that would be amazing.

Comment: See my edit. [DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) is basically a lose description for UPnP, and simplified one could even say it's a "lose synonym". A buzzword to sell stuff, it just defines the minimum standard for media use via UPnP. So if your device is capable of UPnP, it *at least* supports DLNA, usually much more.

Comment: Thanks, BUbbleUPnP is a very nice software. I'm having a lot of fun trying out various combinations. One thing I learned this morning is that I can use VLC to browse and play all content on my phone: video, music and pictures. Video playback intermittently stucks for a split second, very rarely, but it does. That is unfortunate, but I'm wondering if it is a VLC or BubbleUPnP issue, or maybe it's just that two don't get along well. Anyhow, great answer Izzy. Thank you very much for pushing me into a right direction.

Comment: Glad it helped! And thanks for your feedback, which holds very useful details. I hope you don't mind if I include them into my answers (with credits to you, of course) :) // Besides: Thanks especially for the hint to VLC! I wasn't aware VLC can handle DLNA. Very good to know, that's something I can use to check my DLNA server :)